# page not stable whenever user not check any one of the checkboxes and error message not show in the label

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using a label for showing validation error message like below;

```
<table align="center" width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label for="validation_all" id="errormessage" visible="false" style="font-size:60%; color:red;"></label>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

If user would not check any one of the five checkboxes then I want to show validation error message on the label like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#communication_form").submit(function ( event ) {

      var phone_value = $("#cb_Phone").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var email_value = $("#cb_Email").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var skype_value = $("#cb_Skype").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var website_value = $("#cb_Website").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var twitter_value = $("#cb_Twitter").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var hasError1 = false;

      if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
      {
         var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");
         message.show();
      } 
   });
</script>
```

It shows error message in the label but not stable on that page whenever check the checkbox and  and when user check the checkbox it  go forward, I am using below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#communication_form").submit(function ( event ) {

      var phone_value = $("#cb_Phone").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var email_value = $("#cb_Email").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var skype_value = $("#cb_Skype").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var website_value = $("#cb_Website").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var twitter_value = $("#cb_Twitter").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var hasError1 = false;

      if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
      {
         var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");
         message.show();
         hasError1 true;
      } 
      if(hasError1)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
</script>
```

kindly help me waiting for your reply. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still stuck?

```
  if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
  {
     $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");
     hasError1 = true;
  }
```

You were missing `=` between `hasError1` and `true`